# Preselect explanatory variables with PCA for a further multivariate analysis

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, biostatistics, dimensionality-reduction, multidimensional-scaling

I have dataset composed of samples (here corresponding to sites), species, environmental variables linked to the species (e.g.: species biomass, abundance and size) and explanatory variables (Temperature, oxygen,…). The number of explanatory variables is quite consequent. So I wanted to do a PCA on the explanatory variables of the different sites to do a data reduction of explanatory variables. And after include the selected variables on an MDS or a dbRDA with the sites, species and the environmental variables.
Does it make sense?

In my reasoning, if the explanatory variables are not considered as important in contributing to the selected components of the PCA (and then does not influence the dissimilarity among sites). By extension, they will not contribute to influence environmental variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose seems to be to identify predictors that make major contributions to to the first few principal components of the predictor matrix, remove the other predictors, then proceed to model with the remaining predictors.

This could be considered a type of data reduction without reference to the outcome variable, which can be a good idea in general. Frank Harrell discusses several methods for unsupervised data reduction in Section 4.7 of his [RMS course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf).

A potential difficulty with your particular approach is how it will deal with 2 or more highly correlated predictors, as correlated predictors tend to be similarly represented in individual principal components. For such sets of predictors you might want instead to devise some type of combined cluster score. If you just choose one of a set of correlated predictors, your choice might depend heavily on the particular data set.

You also will have to figure out how to explain your predictor-selection approach clearly to others so that they could reproduce your results.

You might also consider methods like ridge regression, LASSO, or their combination in elastic net. If you have multiple outcome variables, an approach like [canonical correlation analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation) or [partial least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression) could be useful.

Comment: Yes that is correct, my idea is to do a data reduction. Thank you for that answer, you provided all the tools I need. 
To avoid highly correlated predictors, my plan was to apply a preliminary VIF (Variance Inflation Factor), on the dataset.